# Center point labels between ticks (Polar Area Chart JS)

Tags: chart.js, styling

I'm using Chart JS in which I have a polar area chart (see image https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1CQs.jpg) I want the point labels to be centered between the ticks. I have found solutions that only seem to work with bar charts that have an X and Y axis by using.

```
xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                offsetGridLines: true
            }
        ]}
```

But this does not seem to work when using a polar area chart.

My code is

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Chart from "chart.js";

export default class OrdersFufilledChart extends Component {
  OrdersFufilledChart = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    const OrdersFufilledChart = this.OrdersFufilledChart.current.getContext(
      "2d"
    );

    new Chart(OrdersFufilledChart, {
      type: "polarArea",
        data: {
            datasets: [
                {
                    data: [342, 323, 333, 352, 361, 299, 272, 423, 425, 400, 382, 363],
                    backgroundColor: ["#57C5C8", "#57C5C8", "#57C5C8", "#57C5C8", "#57C5C8", "#ff0931", "#ff0931","#57C5C8","#57C5C8","#57C5C8","#57C5C8","#57C5C8"],
                    borderWidth: 4,
                    hoverBorderColor: "white",
                }
            ],
        labels: [
          "JAN",
          "FEB",
          "MAR",
          "APR",
          "MAY",
          "JUN",
          "JUL",
          "AUG",
          "SEP",
          "OCT",
          "NOV",
          "DEC"
        ],

      },
        options: {

            responsive: true,
            plugins: {
                datalabels: {
                    display: false,
                },

            },
            cutoutPercentage: 20,
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            layout: {
                padding: 0,

            },
            scale: {
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true
                },

           ticks: {
            max: 450,
            maxTicksLimit: 1,
                    display: false,

          },
          angleLines: {
            display: true
          },
            pointLabels: {
                display: true
            }
          },

      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <canvas
          id="OrdersFufilledChart"
          ref={this.OrdersFufilledChart}
          width={360}
          height={360}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Any insight on how I can do this or pointers in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT

I'm looking for something like this with the labels between inbetween. [image: https://imgur.com/gallery/L7P7qmu]

Comment: If you add a Fiddle it will help. https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Trying to add it now but can't seem to get it working on there at the moment

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/5fgs214x/1/

Comment: @IceeFrog something like this https://imgur.com/gallery/L7P7qmu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using the datalabels-plugin for that?

I guess you saw [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59158030/chart-js-polararea-chart-changing-the-labels-to-a-45-degree-angle) where I used this plugin because your code has many similarities to mine.

I improved my code so it's responsive now. The labels are even animated. I don't share OP's concerns of the other question (offtopic: can somebody correct this genitive here? I know it's wrong...) with cluttered labels in this case because of the small 3-char-labels.

Complete code: https://jsbin.com/hamekugoja/2/edit?js,output

```
let myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("pie-chart"), {
  type: "polarArea",
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [342, 323, 333, 352, 361, 299, 272, 423, 425, 400, 382, 363],
      backgroundColor: ["#57C5C8", "#57C5C8", "#57C5C8", "#57C5C8", "#57C5C8", "#ff0931", "#ff0931", "#57C5C8", "#57C5C8", "#57C5C8", "#57C5C8", "#57C5C8"],
      borderWidth: 4,
      hoverBorderColor: "white",
    }],
    labels: [
      "JAN",
      "FEB",
      "MAR",
      "APR",
      "MAY",
      "JUN",
      "JUL",
      "AUG",
      "SEP",
      "OCT",
      "NOV",
      "DEC"
    ],
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        formatter: function(value, context) {
          return context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex];
        },
        anchor: 'start',
        align: 'end',
        offset: 0 // Gets updated
      },
    },
    cutoutPercentage: 20,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    layout: {
      padding: 30,
    },
    scale: {
      scaleLabel: {
        display: true
      },
      ticks: {
        max: 450,
        maxTicksLimit: 1,
        display: false,
      },
      angleLines: {
        display: true
      },
      pointLabels: {
        display: false
      }
    },
    onResize: function() {
      let width = document.getElementById("pie-chart").width
      let padding = myChart.options.layout.padding
      myChart.options.plugins.datalabels.offset = width/2-padding
    }
  }
});

function updateOffset() {
  let width = document.getElementById("pie-chart").width
  let padding = myChart.options.layout.padding
  myChart.options.plugins.datalabels.offset = width/2-padding
  myChart.update()
}
updateOffset() //init call after we know the dimensions of the chart
```

Comment: Slightly cleaner version, less code duplication, using arguments from onResize, using correct width: https://codepen.io/peteruithoven/pen/mdwxaMP?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing around with the docs in chartjs, the only thing I was able to achieve is to center the ticks but the lines of the polar graph are hidden because of something white drawn around the ticks once they are drawn

Polar Charts have a single axis, this means it's a radial chart, there's a single axis th at maps points in the angular and radial directions, these is known as 'radial axes'.

I played with Linear Radial Axis docs from chartjs and was able to center the ticks, hope this may lead to anything helpful in your question

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head> <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link  id='GoogleFontsLink' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'><link  id='GoogleFontsLink' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crete Round' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'><link  id='GoogleFontsLink' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coming Soon' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'><link  id='GoogleFontsLink' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'><link  id='GoogleFontsLink' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script>
 WebFontConfig = {
 google: 
{families: ["Open Sans","Crete Round","Coming Soon","Play","Cabin",]},active: function() { 
 DrawTheChart(ChartData,ChartOptions,"chart-01","PolarArea")}
};
  </script>
  <script asyn src="https://livegap.com/charts/js/webfont.js">
  </script><script src="https://livegap.com/charts/js/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script>
function DrawTheChart(ChartData,ChartOptions,ChartId,ChartType){
eval('var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById(ChartId).getContext("2d")).'+ChartType+'(ChartData,ChartOptions);document.getElementById(ChartId).getContext("2d").stroke();')
}
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <canvas  id="chart-01" width="500" height="500"  style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00);border-radius:0px;width:500px;height:500px;padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px"></canvas>
  <script> function MoreChartOptions(){} var ChartData = [{value :65,
color:'rgba(52,152,219,1)',title:'enero'},{value :8,color:'rgba(46,204,113,1)',title:'febrero'},{value :90,color:'rgba(166,107,190,1)',title:'marzo'},{value :81,color:'rgba(241,196,15,1)',title:'abril'},{value :56,color:'rgba(230,126,34,1)',title:'mayo'},{value :55,color:'rgba(192,58,43,1)',title:'junio'},{value :40,color:'rgba(141,68,173,1)',title:'julio'},];ChartOptions= {decimalSeparator:".",thousandSeparator:",",spaceLeft:12,spaceRight:12,spaceTop:12,spaceBottom:12,scaleLabel:"<%=value+''%>",yAxisMinimumInterval:'none',scaleShowLabels:false,scaleShowLine:false,scaleLineStyle:"solid",scaleLineWidth:1,scaleLineColor:"rgba(0,0,0,0.6)",scaleOverlay :false,scaleOverride :false,scaleSteps:10,scaleStepWidth:10,scaleStartValue:0,inGraphDataShow:true,inGraphDataTmpl:'<%=v2%>',inGraphDataFontFamily:"'Crete Round'",inGraphDataFontStyle:"normal normal",inGraphDataFontColor:"rgba(51,51,51,1)",inGraphDataFontSize:15,inGraphDataPaddingX:0,inGraphDataPaddingY:0,inGraphDataAlign:"center",inGraphDataVAlign:"middle",inGraphDataXPosition:2,inGraphDataYPosition:3,inGraphDataAnglePosition:2,inGraphDataRadiusPosition:3,inGraphDataRotate:0,inGraphDataPaddingAngle:0,inGraphDataPaddingRadius:15, inGraphDataBorders:false,inGraphDataBordersXSpace:1,inGraphDataBordersYSpace:1,inGraphDataBordersWidth:1,inGraphDataBordersStyle:"solid",inGraphDataBordersColor:"rgba(0,0,0,1)",legend:true,maxLegendCols:5,legendBlockSize:20,legendFillColor:'rgba(255,255,255,0.00)',legendColorIndicatorStrokeWidth:1,legendPosX:-2,legendPosY:4,legendXPadding:0,legendYPadding:0,legendBorders:false,legendBordersWidth:1,legendBordersStyle:"solid",legendBordersColors:"rgba(102,102,102,1)",legendBordersSpaceBefore:5,legendBordersSpaceLeft:5,legendBordersSpaceRight:5,legendBordersSpaceAfter:5,legendSpaceBeforeText:5,legendSpaceLeftText:5,legendSpaceRightText:5,legendSpaceAfterText:5,legendSpaceBetweenBoxAndText:5,legendSpaceBetweenTextHorizontal:5,legendSpaceBetweenTextVertical:5,legendFontFamily:"'Cabin'",legendFontStyle:"normal normal",legendFontColor:"rgba(0,0,0,1)",legendFontSize:15,showYAxisMin:false,rotateLabels:"smart",xAxisBottom:true,yAxisLeft:true,yAxisRight:false,graphTitleSpaceBefore:5,graphTitleSpaceAfter:5, graphTitleBorders:false,graphTitleBordersXSpace:1,graphTitleBordersYSpace:1,graphTitleBordersWidth:1,graphTitleBordersStyle:"solid",graphTitleBordersColor:"rgba(0,0,0,1)",graphTitle : "Gráfico Título",graphTitleFontFamily:"'Coming Soon'",graphTitleFontStyle:"normal normal",graphTitleFontColor:"rgba(52,152,219,1)",graphTitleFontSize:33,graphSubTitleSpaceBefore:-8,graphSubTitleSpaceAfter:3, graphSubTitleBorders:false,graphSubTitleBordersXSpace:1,graphSubTitleBordersYSpace:1,graphSubTitleBordersWidth:1,graphSubTitleBordersStyle:"solid",graphSubTitleBordersColor:"rgba(0,0,0,1)",graphSubTitle : "Añadir título sub aquí",graphSubTitleFontFamily:"'Play'",graphSubTitleFontStyle:"normal normal",graphSubTitleFontColor:"rgba(10,10,10,1)",graphSubTitleFontSize:14,scaleFontFamily:"'Open Sans'",scaleFontStyle:"normal normal",scaleFontColor:"rgba(0,0,0,1)",scaleFontSize:12,pointLabelFontFamily:"'Open Sans'",pointLabelFontStyle:"normal normal",pointLabelFontColor:"rgba(102,102,102,1)",pointLabelFontSize:12,angleShowLineOut:true,angleLineStyle:"solid",angleLineWidth:1,angleLineColor:"rgba(0,0,0,0.1)",percentageInnerCutout:50,scaleShowGridLines:true,scaleGridLineStyle:"solid",scaleGridLineWidth:1,scaleGridLineColor:"rgba(0,0,0,0.1)",scaleXGridLinesStep:1,scaleYGridLinesStep:3,segmentShowStroke:true,segmentStrokeStyle:"solid",segmentStrokeWidth:2,segmentStrokeColor:"rgba(255,255,255,1.00)",datasetStroke:true,datasetFill : true,datasetStrokeStyle:"solid",datasetStrokeWidth:2,bezierCurve:true,bezierCurveTension :0.4,pointDotStrokeStyle:"solid",pointDotStrokeWidth : 1,pointDotRadius : 3,pointDot : true,scaleTickSizeBottom:5,scaleTickSizeTop:5,scaleTickSizeLeft:5,scaleTickSizeRight:5,graphMin:0,barShowStroke : false,barBorderRadius:0,barStrokeStyle:"solid",barStrokeWidth:1,barValueSpacing:15,barDatasetSpacing:0,scaleShowLabelBackdrop :true,scaleBackdropColor:'rgba(255,255,255,0.75)',scaleBackdropPaddingX :2,scaleBackdropPaddingY :2,animation : true,onAnimationComplete : function(){MoreChartOptions()}};
 DrawTheChart(ChartData,ChartOptions,"chart-01","PolarArea");</script></body></html>
```

Check out what I did on `ticks:{},` and `angeLines:{},`

You might want to take a look at the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/linear.html#linear-radial-axis), anyway tbh I think you'll have to go into [New Axes](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/axes.html) and extend your polar chart to fulfill your needs.

Do you mind trying to use another chart generator? [Try this](https://livegap.com/charts/app.php?lan=es)

Comment: I think I have explained it badly. I'm wanting to move the labels (months of the year) so they are centered between the ticks not on the line

Comment: Oh I understand your need, I'll play with the docs later to try this idea out :)

Comment: What about using another chartjs, probably the one I shared works out for you, maybe try highcharts, I've read docs on polar areas from chartjs and I could not find a way to assist you with your requirement sorry :(